# How to add more than one child under same parent in Firebase Realtime Database without using push()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to `Firebase Realtime Database`, I want to generate the **unique key** under parent node without using **push()**.As push() generate the random unique key of 128 bit.

I want my current date to be the unique key under parent node. If date did not match with the last child of parent node then it must generate a new node in the parent.

Below mentioned is my code:

```
     Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://maps-abcdxyz.firebaseio.com/user");
                    if (s.equals("null"))
                    {
                        String key = reference.child("User").push().getKey();

                        String inStatus = "1";

                        UserData user = new UserData(attendIN,"0","0","0");
                        Map<String, Object> postValues = user.inoutTime();
                        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                        childUpdates.put( "/" + username + "/" + month_name + "/" + todayDate ,postValues);

                        reference.updateChildren(childUpdates);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"In Time Submitted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(jInStatus.equals("1"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"In time already Submitted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Firebase referenceDate = new Firebase("https://maps-abcdxyz.firebaseio.com/user/" + username +
                                    "/" + month_name);

                            String inStatus = "1";
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
                            FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference("/" + "user" + "/" + username + "/"+ month_name + "/");
                            UserData user = new UserData(attendIN,inStatus,"0","0");
                            Map<String, Object> postValues = user.inoutTime();
                            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                            myRef.child(todayDate).setValue(postValues);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"In Time Submitted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every node in a Firebase database is a `Map`. As I see in your code, you are using the same value for `todayDate` even if you are adding data or you are updating data. So, in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one, ending in having a single child.

To solve this, you need to use a different value for your node. I suggest you use the randon generated key provided bt the `push()` method instead of using the date.

Comment: I don't want to use push(), I know it will create the random unique id for me.I want that my dates must be unique id for me.The next child must be the tomorrow date.

Comment: Then change the the value of your `todayDate` to be `tomorrow` and use it in your reference accordingly. Then youl have another child in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was updating the status on the same date thats why it was not creating the other key in tree structure.